# How to configure Sonarqube Quality Gate inorder to sent email alert everytime there is low code coverage than thresold value

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube Quality Gate is a great feature but the only problem I am having is that we dont get email alert everytime there is low code coverage on new code less than quality gate thresold value.

**For example:** Quality Gate Thresold value for code coverage on new code < 80% send email alert

- 1st analysis : code coverage is 85%
- 2nd analysis : code coverage is 70% - email alert received.
  -- Quality gate status: Orange 
  -- New quality gate threshold:Coverage on new code < 80 since  
  ...
- 3rd analysis : code coverage is 67% - no email alert is received.
- 4th analysis : code coverage is 50% - no email alert is received.

The email alert is received only when the color/state changes from one to another. We would like to setup email alert for every analysis it runs and if the code coverage on new code is less than thresold value, trigger email.

Answer (score 1):

Automated emails can be configured only for following points.

1. Changes in issues assigned to any user or reported by user
2. New false positives
3. New issues
4. New quality gate status (fail to pass    and    pass to fail)

Once there are any changes identified by Sonar Analysis in the above mentioned points , SonarQube will send emails to every member of the team.

for more details you can check the user profile.

Comment: There's no concept of a "team" in Sonarqube that I can find. There are Groups. So let's say I have 10 users and 8 projects in SonarQube. I have configured my email server in Sonarqube but haven't found anywhere to configure rules around when emails are sent and why. If an Analysis triggers a quality gate for one of the 8 projects, will it automatically email all 10 users?

Comment: Right, @KevinM but also think if you have 100+ user and same 100+ project( consider you are working on a centralized Sonar) then do you still want to unnecessary bug all 100 users even if they are not interested...

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to the SonarQube portal
2. Click to Administrations Tab
3. By Default Configuration tab is selected now Click to Genral Tab
4. Search Email in Browser or Scroll down Until Email tab
5. Provide the Email prefix as per your project requirement

   ```
   Default-  [SONARQUBE] 
   Custom - [companyname-SONARQUBE]
   ```
6. Provide the From address
7. Provide the From name
8. Secure connection - startls or ssl
9. Provide the name of SMTP server. (e.g. If your configuring gmail then the SMTP server is `smtp.gmail.com`)
10. Provide the Email Password, SMTP Port, & Username.
11. You can test the email configurations Using Test Configuration options.

Comment: SMTP port should be 587 with `starttls` secure connection and `smtp.gmail.com` SMTP server